# Receiving user input after reading piped input

Tags: c#, .net, io, console-application, stdin

I am writing a small, interactive console application in .NET 4. I want to extend this to be able to handle optional redirected input as well, like:

```
echo hello | myapp.exe
```

Trouble is of course that the redirected input steals the "keyboard stream", so any calls to Console.Read*() returns null.

What I have at the moment is:

```
// Read piped input
try
{
    bool keyAvailable = Console.KeyAvailable;
}
catch
{
    string redirected = Console.In.ReadToEnd();
    // Need to do something here to "un-redirect" stdin back to keyboard
}

// Always returns null
String userInput = Console.ReadLine();
```

On UNIX I could open a stream to /dev/tty to get user input, but how can I make this work on Windows?

Thanks!

[EDIT]

**Working solution based on Craig's answer:**

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool FreeConsole();

try
{
     bool keyAvailable = Console.KeyAvailable;
}
catch
{
    string redirectedInput = Console.In.ReadToEnd();
    bool freed = FreeConsole();
    bool attached = AttachConsole(-1);
    Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput()));
}
```

I have to start by detaching from the console altogether using

```
FreeConsole().
```

I could opt to create an entirely new console using

```
AllocConsole()
```

but that would create another console window, which I don't really want. Instead I attach to the parent console (the existing cmd.exe) using

```
AttachConsole(-1) // -1 = "Parent".
```

I can only speculate that the .NET class Console holds a reference to the previous stdin stream, but only after the call to `Console.SetIn()` the `Console.ReadLine()` is back to it's blocking behavior, waiting for user input.

Now on to investigate what happens if I run with my application's stdout redirected:

```
echo hello | myapp.exe | somewhere ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AttachConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function should do the job, though I've only used it to regain output rather than input.

Comment: Using a combination of P/Invoke ofFreeConsole()/AttachConsole() and Console.SetIn() actually works, thanks!! (I'll update the original post to show the complete code)