# restoring keyboard input / disabling cmd prompt redirection

Tags: c#, input, io-redirection

I am working on a C#/Visual Studio project that takes input from a file, does stuff with it, and then gives a info splash.  The problem I'm having comes from wanting to keep the info on the screen/keep the program open indefinitely.  Normally I would use a simple Console.ReadLine() or ReadKey(), but neither works with the redirection (program < file under properties/command line arguments).

I have tried using a variety of the Console commands and none of them seem to shut off the file redirection and restore "normal" input.  Is this not possible with a command prompt redirection?

Comment: You probably can't do that

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779818/receiving-user-input-after-reading-piped-input

Answer (score 0):

Your software only has one input stream, and that one is either connected to the command line window (which is opened on demand if there is none, and then also closes after your program is finished), or to a file. Your program has no control over this input stream, this is managed by Windows (the command shell host window).

You can open cmd.exe manually and start your program in there, then the window will stay open, or use `cmd.exe /K "program.exe < file"` to do this in one step, or rewrite your software to allow it to open the file itself with a certain parameter, e.g. `program --in file` .